# When are newline characters significant in Verilog compiler directives?

Tags: verilog, newline, preprocessor

I'm trying to parse Verilog code including Verilog compiler directives.
My parser presently insists that such directives generally end with a newline, e.g.

```
`ifdef foo <newline>
```

This was inspired by an absence of any discussion of compiler directives in early Verilog standards other than roughly "directives may occur anywhere in the source", and all examples that I had found did not violate this rule.  Given that compiler directives are arguably inspired by "C", and C's directives must end on a newline, this seemed reasonable.

I've run into the following line in an open source specification a CPU, which I believe to be thoroughly tested (i.e. valid) code:

```
`ifdef PR_ERROR if ($time > 1 && rst_l) `PR_ERROR("dmu_ilu_cib_addr_decode",`MON_ERROR,"ERROR: Instance ID for module dmu_ilu_cib_csr is bad"); `endif
```

Note the absence of a newline after PR_ERROR.   Is this legal?

The IEEE1800-2012 Verilog standards document is a little hard to interpret.

Page 639 says

> Only white space or a comment may appear on the same line as the
> `include compiler directive.

So the standard clearly insists on a newline for `include.

There is no such similar statement made for other compiler directives.
In particular, page 685 discusses `` `ifdef ``, `` `else ``, `` `elsif ``, `` `endif ``, and only says:

> These directives may appear anywhere in the source description.

If one believes that standard is well-defined, and what is not forbidden is allowed,
one might believe that newlines are not needed for such directives.  I'd be happy to see a chapter-and-verse quote that is explicit.

Regardless, what do the compilers actually accept?

Comment: Don't see "broadness"; asked very specific request on whether newline is allowed for `ifdef and then generalized to other compiler directives.  Thanks for pointers to other docs and tools to try for actual behavior.

Comment: FWIW: I experimentally removed the "ends with newline" grammar constraint on the conditional directives, and was able to parse without complaints an additional hundred files out the 1800 files comprising my lab-rat microprocessor Verilog source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Section **22.6 `ifdef, `else, `elsif, `endif, `ifndef** of the 1800-2017 LRM says "These directives may appear anywhere in the source description.", the rest of that section defines the behavior in terms of "groups of lines". A strict interpretation of that section would mean that the following would *not* be allowed on one line:

```
`ifdef A initial $display("A"); `else initial $display("not A"); `endif
```

However all tools seem to support this.

But interaction with other compiler directive can leave room for ambiguity

```
`ifdef A `define X 2 `endif
```

If `A` is not defined, is the  `` `endif `` part of the macro not compliled or the end of the  `` `ifdef ``?

So my recommendation would be to keep the conditional compilation directives on separate lines.

Comment: This isn't about what *I* write.   (I agree: best stylewise and for maximizing compatibly with Verilog processors if one writes compiler compilation directives on separate lines.)  It is about what constitutes legal code from another party that has beeen writing code that his tools consider legal,  that my parser has to swallow.

Comment: The LRM is ambiguous here and I've filled an errata to have it addressed. https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=7258. The code you wrote seems to be supported by all simulators on http://www.edaplayground.com

Comment: Guess I'm not surprised that you consider it vague.   Thanks for that last bit; I think you saved me hours and hours of experimentation.